# PrintWriter in Scala not writing to file?

Tags: scala, file-io

I have the following file creation/writing code:

```
val file =  new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(new File(TMP_DIR, fileName), true))
    file.write(getFirstRow(tableName))
```

For some weird reason, it's not writing to my file, but it creates it everytime. The getFirstRow method returns a string that I want to append to the file. What is going wrong?

Comment: How about calling "flush" after the call to write ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are neither `flush`ing nor `close`ing the `File` (or the `PrintWriter`, which would also do that).

This is such a common mistake that it's a fantastic opportunity to use an example of the [Loan Pattern](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SYGN/Loan):

```
def withPrintWriter(dir:String, name:String)(f: (PrintWriter) => Any) {
  val file = new File(dir, name)
  val writer = new FileWriter(file)
  val printWriter = new PrintWriter(writer)
  try {
    f(printWriter)
  }
  finally {
    printWriter.close()
  }
```

}

Which you use like this:

```
withPrintWriter("/tmp", "myFile") { printWriter =>
  printWriter.write("all good")
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you also use an implicit to clean them up more?